# Change visible OS Name

Tags: linux-mint, rename, distributions

I have a Linux Mint 18.3 installation that I have heavily modified. I'm wanting to change the name of this installation so to a normal person, it isn't Linux Mint, but some other weird distro (cause reasons).

I have changed `/etc/lsb-release` , `/etc/os-release` , and `/etc/upstream-release/lsb-release` all to reflect the name I'm wanting. However, this is the result I am getting:

[image]

As you can see under `Base System` it has "Eleftheria 3.0 Meteor" (the name I'm going for), but up at the top it still says Ubuntu.

I want to change it so the user sees a different OS but the system still recognizes it as Linux Mint/Ubuntu, so I don't have issues with apps and what not.

Is this all i can do? Or can I modify something else to reflect the desired name?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Output of `sudo grep -wi ubuntu /etc/*` :

```
grep: /etc/acpi: Is a directory
grep: /etc/alternatives: Is a directory
grep: /etc/apm: Is a directory
grep: /etc/apparmor: Is a directory
grep: /etc/apparmor.d: Is a directory
grep: /etc/apport: Is a directory
grep: /etc/apt: Is a directory
grep: /etc/at-spi2: Is a directory
grep: /etc/avahi: Is a directory
grep: /etc/bash_completion.d: Is a directory
grep: /etc/binfmt.d: Is a directory
grep: /etc/bluetooth: Is a directory
grep: /etc/brltty: Is a directory
grep: /etc/ca-certificates: Is a directory
grep: /etc/calendar: Is a directory
/etc/casper.conf:export BUILD_SYSTEM="Ubuntu"
grep: /etc/chatscripts: Is a directory
grep: /etc/chromium-browser: Is a directory
grep: /etc/cinnamon: Is a directory
grep: /etc/clamav: Is a directory
grep: /etc/ConsoleKit: Is a directory
grep: /etc/console-setup: Is a directory
grep: /etc/cracklib: Is a directory
grep: /etc/cron.d: Is a directory
grep: /etc/cron.daily: Is a directory
grep: /etc/cron.hourly: Is a directory
grep: /etc/cron.monthly: Is a directory
grep: /etc/cron.weekly: Is a directory
grep: /etc/cups: Is a directory
grep: /etc/cupshelpers: Is a directory
grep: /etc/dbus-1: Is a directory
grep: /etc/default: Is a directory
grep: /etc/depmod.d: Is a directory
grep: /etc/dhcp: Is a directory
grep: /etc/dictionaries-common: Is a directory
grep: /etc/dkms: Is a directory
grep: /etc/dnsmasq.d: Is a directory
grep: /etc/doc-base: Is a directory
grep: /etc/dpkg: Is a directory
grep: /etc/emacs: Is a directory
grep: /etc/esound: Is a directory
grep: /etc/firefox: Is a directory
grep: /etc/fonts: Is a directory
grep: /etc/gconf: Is a directory
grep: /etc/gdb: Is a directory
grep: /etc/gdm3: Is a directory
grep: /etc/ghostscript: Is a directory
grep: /etc/gimp: Is a directory
grep: /etc/gnome: Is a directory
grep: /etc/gnome-app-install: Is a directory
grep: /etc/gnome-vfs-2.0: Is a directory
grep: /etc/groff: Is a directory
grep: /etc/grub.d: Is a directory
grep: /etc/gss: Is a directory
grep: /etc/gtk-2.0: Is a directory
grep: /etc/gtk-3.0: Is a directory
grep: /etc/guest-session: Is a directory
grep: /etc/gufw: Is a directory
grep: /etc/hp: Is a directory
grep: /etc/ifplugd: Is a directory
grep: /etc/ImageMagick-6: Is a directory
grep: /etc/init: Is a directory
grep: /etc/init.d: Is a directory
grep: /etc/initramfs-tools: Is a directory
grep: /etc/insserv: Is a directory
grep: /etc/insserv.conf.d: Is a directory
grep: /etc/iproute2: Is a directory
grep: /etc/kbd: Is a directory
grep: /etc/kernel: Is a directory
grep: /etc/ldap: Is a directory
grep: /etc/ld.so.conf.d: Is a directory
grep: /etc/libnl-3: Is a directory
grep: /etc/libpaper.d: Is a directory
grep: /etc/libreoffice: Is a directory
grep: /etc/lightdm: Is a directory
grep: /etc/linuxmint: Is a directory
grep: /etc/logcheck: Is a directory
grep: /etc/logrotate.d: Is a directory
grep: /etc/lvm: Is a directory
grep: /etc/menu-methods: Is a directory
grep: /etc/modprobe.d: Is a directory
grep: /etc/modules-load.d: Is a directory
grep: /etc/mono: Is a directory
grep: /etc/network: Is a directory
grep: /etc/NetworkManager: Is a directory
grep: /etc/newt: Is a directory
/etc/ntp.conf:# Use servers from the NTP Pool Project. Approved by Ubuntu Technical Board
/etc/ntp.conf:pool 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org iburst
/etc/ntp.conf:pool 1.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org iburst
/etc/ntp.conf:pool 2.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org iburst
/etc/ntp.conf:pool 3.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org iburst
/etc/ntp.conf:# Use Ubuntu's ntp server as a fallback.
/etc/ntp.conf:pool ntp.ubuntu.com
grep: /etc/obex-data-server: Is a directory
grep: /etc/openal: Is a directory
grep: /etc/openvpn: Is a directory
grep: /etc/opt: Is a directory
/etc/os-release:ID_LIKE=ubuntu
grep: /etc/pam.d: Is a directory
grep: /etc/pcmcia: Is a directory
grep: /etc/perl: Is a directory
grep: /etc/pki: Is a directory
grep: /etc/pm: Is a directory
grep: /etc/polkit-1: Is a directory
grep: /etc/ppp: Is a directory
grep: /etc/profile.d: Is a directory
grep: /etc/pulse: Is a directory
grep: /etc/purple: Is a directory
grep: /etc/python: Is a directory
grep: /etc/python2.7: Is a directory
grep: /etc/python3: Is a directory
grep: /etc/python3.5: Is a directory
grep: /etc/rc0.d: Is a directory
grep: /etc/rc1.d: Is a directory
grep: /etc/rc2.d: Is a directory
grep: /etc/rc3.d: Is a directory
grep: /etc/rc4.d: Is a directory
grep: /etc/rc5.d: Is a directory
grep: /etc/rc6.d: Is a directory
grep: /etc/rcS.d: Is a directory
grep: /etc/request-key.d: Is a directory
grep: /etc/resolvconf: Is a directory
grep: /etc/rsyslog.d: Is a directory
grep: /etc/samba: Is a directory
grep: /etc/sane.d: Is a directory
grep: /etc/security: Is a directory
grep: /etc/selinux: Is a directory
grep: /etc/sensors.d: Is a directory
grep: /etc/sgml: Is a directory
grep: /etc/signon-ui: Is a directory
grep: /etc/skel: Is a directory
grep: /etc/speech-dispatcher: Is a directory
grep: /etc/ssh: Is a directory
grep: /etc/ssl: Is a directory
grep: /etc/sudoers.d: Is a directory
grep: /etc/sysctl.d: Is a directory
grep: /etc/systemd: Is a directory
grep: /etc/terminfo: Is a directory
grep: /etc/thermald: Is a directory
grep: /etc/tmpfiles.d: Is a directory
grep: /etc/udev: Is a directory
grep: /etc/udisks2: Is a directory
grep: /etc/ufw: Is a directory
grep: /etc/update-motd.d: Is a directory
grep: /etc/UPower: Is a directory
/etc/upstart-xsessions:ubuntu
grep: /etc/upstream-release: Is a directory
grep: /etc/usb_modeswitch.d: Is a directory
grep: /etc/vbox: Is a directory
grep: /etc/vim: Is a directory
grep: /etc/wildmidi: Is a directory
grep: /etc/wpa_supplicant: Is a directory
grep: /etc/X11: Is a directory
grep: /etc/xdg: Is a directory
grep: /etc/xml: Is a directory
```

**EDIT**

Contents of `/etc/os-release`:

[image]

I left things I felt would damage system functionality if changed.

**EDIT**

Output of `find /usr/share/ -type f -iname \*ubuntu\*png`

```
/usr/share/linuxmint/mintinstall/icons/ubuntu-tweak.png
/usr/share/linuxmint/mintinstall/icons/ubuntuone.png
/usr/share/linuxmint/mintinstall/icons/firefox-ubuntu-it-menu.png
/usr/share/linuxmint/mintinstall/icons/edubuntu.png
/usr/share/linuxmint/mintinstall/installed/ubuntu-tweak.png
/usr/share/linuxmint/mintinstall/installed/ubuntuone.png
/usr/share/linuxmint/mintinstall/installed/firefox-ubuntu-it-menu.png
/usr/share/linuxmint/mintinstall/installed/edubuntu.png
/usr/share/app-install/icons/_usr_share_cordova-ubuntu-tests_cordovaqt64.png
/usr/share/app-install/icons/lubuntu-software-center.png
/usr/share/app-install/icons/ubuntu-qtcreator.png
/usr/share/app-install/icons/ubuntustudio-controls.png
/usr/share/app-install/icons/ubuntu-online-tour.png
/usr/share/app-install/icons/firefox-ubuntu-it-menu.png
/usr/share/app-install/icons/edubuntu.png
/usr/share/app-install/icons/_usr_share_cordova-ubuntu-2.8_examples_qrcode-scanner_img_qrcode.png
/usr/share/app-install/icons/_usr_share_ubuntu_settings_system_system-settings.png
/usr/share/app-install/icons/ubuntustudio-logo.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-X/status/22/ubuntuone-client-offline.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-X/status/22/ubuntuone-client-updating.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-X/status/22/ubuntuone-client-idle.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-X/status/22/ubuntuone-client-error.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-X/status/24/ubuntuone-client-offline.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-X/status/24/ubuntuone-client-updating.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-X/status/24/ubuntuone-client-idle.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-X/status/24/ubuntuone-client-error.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-X/apps/22/ubuntu-tweak.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-X/apps/22/ubuntuone.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-X/apps/22/softwarecenter-ubuntu.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-X/apps/16/ubuntu-tweak.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-X/apps/16/ubuntuone.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-X/apps/16/softwarecenter-ubuntu.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-X/apps/48/ubuntu-tweak.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-X/apps/48/ubuntuone.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-X/apps/48/softwarecenter-ubuntu.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-X/apps/32/ubuntu-tweak.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-X/apps/32/ubuntuone.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-X/apps/32/softwarecenter-ubuntu.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-X/apps/24/ubuntu-tweak.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-X/apps/24/ubuntuone.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-X/apps/24/softwarecenter-ubuntu.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-X/emblems/22/emblem-ubuntuone-synchronized.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-X/emblems/22/emblem-ubuntuone-updating.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-X/emblems/22/emblem-ubuntuone-unsynchronized.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-X/emblems/16/emblem-ubuntuone-synchronized.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-X/emblems/16/emblem-ubuntuone-updating.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-X/emblems/16/emblem-ubuntuone-unsynchronized.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-X/emblems/48/emblem-ubuntuone-synchronized.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-X/emblems/48/emblem-ubuntuone-updating.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-X/emblems/48/emblem-ubuntuone-unsynchronized.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-X/emblems/32/emblem-ubuntuone-synchronized.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-X/emblems/32/emblem-ubuntuone-updating.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-X/emblems/32/emblem-ubuntuone-unsynchronized.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-X/emblems/24/emblem-ubuntuone-synchronized.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-X/emblems/24/emblem-ubuntuone-updating.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-X/emblems/24/emblem-ubuntuone-unsynchronized.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-X-Dark/status/22/ubuntuone-client-offline.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-X-Dark/status/22/ubuntuone-client-updating.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-X-Dark/status/22/ubuntuone-client-idle.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-X-Dark/status/22/ubuntuone-client-error.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-X-Dark/status/24/ubuntuone-client-offline.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-X-Dark/status/24/ubuntuone-client-updating.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-X-Dark/status/24/ubuntuone-client-idle.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-X-Dark/status/24/ubuntuone-client-error.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-X-Dark/places/22/start-here-ubuntu.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-X-Dark/places/24/start-here-ubuntu.png
/usr/share/icons/gnome/32x32/places/ubuntu-logo.png
/usr/share/icons/gnome/22x22/places/ubuntu-logo.png
/usr/share/icons/gnome/16x16/places/ubuntu-logo.png
/usr/share/icons/gnome/24x24/places/ubuntu-logo.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/apps/ubuntuone-music.png
/usr/share/icons/unity-webapps-applications/apps/64/ubuntuone-music.png
/usr/share/icons/unity-webapps-applications/apps/48/ubuntuone-music.png
/usr/share/icons/unity-webapps-applications/apps/128/ubuntuone-music.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/22/web-omgubuntu.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/22/ubuntuone-music.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/22/ubuntu-tweak.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/22/ubuntuone.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/22/ubuntu-sdk.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/16/web-omgubuntu.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/16/ubuntuone-music.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/16/ubuntu-tweak.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/16/ubuntuone.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/16/ubuntu-sdk.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/64/web-omgubuntu.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/64/ubuntuone-music.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/64/ubuntu-tweak.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/64/ubuntuone.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/64/ubuntu-sdk.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/48/web-omgubuntu.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/48/ubuntuone-music.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/48/ubuntu-tweak.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/48/ubuntuone.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/48/ubuntu-sdk.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/32/web-omgubuntu.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/32/ubuntuone-music.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/32/ubuntu-tweak.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/32/ubuntuone.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/32/ubuntu-sdk.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/96/web-omgubuntu.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/96/ubuntuone-music.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/96/ubuntu-tweak.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/96/ubuntuone.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/96/ubuntu-sdk.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/256/web-omgubuntu.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/256/ubuntuone-music.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/256/ubuntu-tweak.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/256/ubuntuone.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/256/ubuntu-sdk.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/24/web-omgubuntu.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/24/ubuntuone-music.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/24/ubuntu-tweak.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/24/ubuntuone.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/24/ubuntu-sdk.png
/usr/share/plymouth/ubuntu-logo.png
```

Comment: the local topic https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/268551/fully-rename-my-own-gnu-linux-distribution may help you to find how to rename your distribution

Comment: Please execute `grep -wi ubuntu /etc/*` as root and post the output here. Then we may find the source of the "Ubuntu" text.

Comment: @Ned64 I added the requested output. It's pretty extensive.

Comment: It is probably easier debugging that app to learn where the name is coming from.

Comment: OK, you could have a look at `/etc/os-release`, but also (a) it could be an image (what program is this? where does it keeps its graphics?) (b) we might need to look elsewhere.

Comment: It seems to be added at compile time: https://askubuntu.com/questions/623613/wrong-distro-and-logo-in-gnome-control-center . You'll have to get the source and recompile the program with the new branding.

Comment: OK, let's try `find /usr/share/ -type f -iname \*ubuntu\*png` and see where it gets us. I do not believe a PNG image will be compiled into an ELF, though it's possible.

Comment: Of course, if you find an image, open it to see whether it is the one. if so, make a backup, then edit it and look whether the program looks different.

Comment: I don't know about you guys, but I'm not seeing any pics it could be. I checked a few but came up empty.

Comment: @Ned64 You can add any kind of data to an *elf*, I just believe it is not usual, but it is certainly possible. (I am not making a mistake, adding instead of compiling, elf metadata)

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro That's what I said?!

Comment: @Ned64 Did not read it that way, sorry, my fault. You can add it after compiling too.

Comment: @Ned64 @RuiFRibeiro I searched my entire system for files with `*-release` in the name and checked them all. I came up with little more than the `lsb-release` and `os-release` files and what was new was virtually useless.

Comment: What you could do in order to find out whether this is a file is to use `strace gnome-control-center >& strace.out` (that is the program in question, right?) and then filter the output file `strace.out` for `open` syscalls. Look at those files.  Exit the program as quickly as possible after the logo is displayed so that the output is not as big. (strace may need to be installed if you do not have it).

Comment: @Ned64 I checked a few different times and nothing really popped out (granted there where A LOT of files so i may very well have missed something). Any other ideas?

Comment: I am sure there are fewer files if you ignore *.so and *.xml, also filter like `egrep '^open' strace.out`.

Comment: @Ned64 After using `egrep` a few times and whittling things down, it wasn't there.

Comment: @DorkFlower Too bad. Was `gnome-control-center` the right command, though?

Comment: @Ned64 Yes, it was.